# Double coloured Topbar on both meta and Photo.SE

Tags: bug

The new topbar suddenly has two colours. This happens both in Firefox and Safari on a Mac.
[image]

[image]

As you can see, directly above the `S` of StackExchange the colour changes to a different hue.
As other SE sites have a single colour topbar I suspect this is a bug. Anyone else with a similar problem?

Comment: I believe it is caused by the new StackExchange design. From what I can tell, the avatar photo is the largest item in that bar, and it looks thicker on PhotoSE than on other SE sites.

Comment: Avatars between Pets and Photography look the same to me, but we have a fairly customized look and feel for our site as a whole and so it may need a bit of tweaking to look right for us.

Comment: Already posted on MSO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210346/top-bar-with-double-color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have pushed a fix for this. Will go live after the next production build.

Comment: Looks fixed on the other sites, still seems broken on this one. If I remember correctly, we have a pretty unique header configuration.

Comment: Ah I found out why: there hasn't been a production build since I pushed the fix to dev last Friday. It should be out today(Monday). I'll keep you posted.

Comment: JoanneC: should be fixed now on live.

Comment: Sweet, looks good now!